# Character restriction in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, regex, post

I have this code and would like to restrict the characters to [a-f][A-F][0-9]

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dgt']);
$len = strlen($code);
if (!($len == "32" or $len == "40")) {
   print "This is not a valid code.";
} else {
   echo 'success';
}
```

right now it has a character **LENGTH** limit and would like to add characters restriction as stated above.

what's the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make use of a simple regex ?

```
    if(preg_match('/[^a-f_\-0-9]/i', $code)) //if this regex doesn't work , make use of /[^a-fA-F0-9]/
    {
      if(strlen($code)==32 || strlen($code)==40)
      {
      echo "This is not a valid code.";
      }
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Success.';
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't that allow characters more than 40 to be entered? also, would this allow A-F chars?

Comment: thank you, one more question though, why did you discard this line: $len = strlen($code);

Comment: He have not discarded that line. He has given code after that line

Comment: @user3125898, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You need to make use of  `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: one more questions Shankar, does the code you provided allow A-Z chars? thanks for the help

Comment: Nope , just G-Z , you can customize as per you needs.

Answer (score 3):

One could even accomplish the character and length assertion in a single regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^([[:xdigit:]]{8}){4,5}$/i')) {
    // valid
}
```

That will match 4*8 (=32) or 5*8 (=40) hexdigits.

---

Btw, you're supposed to apply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) last, or right before interpolating it into SQL strings. It makes little difference here, in particular as the values are asserted already. But modifying strings after SQL-escaping them might in some circumstances undo the escaping.
You might wish to read up on [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/20767765#20767765) anyway. That would have made that note redundant.

Comment: No, not the shown part. I'm just saying it's not necessary anymore to manually take care about such things.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dgt']);
  $len = strlen($code);  

  if (!($len == "32" or $len == "40") or preg_match('/[^a-fA-F0-9]+/i', $code)){
      print "This is not a valid code.";
  } else {
      echo 'success';
  }
```